# Enabling sticky sessions with nginx ingress, not working

Tags: kubernetes

I have a v1.8.4 deployment running nginx ingress controller. I had an ingress which works fine. But now I am trying to enable sticky sessions in it. I used `kubectl edit ing mying` to add these annotations:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: md5
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: foobar
```

But sticky sessions are still not working. Nginx config does not have anything about sticky sessions. Also, `kubectl describe ing mying` does not show the annotations. What is going wrong here?

I also tried the example for sticky sessions [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/27c863085e2503e5f3249b596f24529fc2488baa/docs/examples/affinity/cookie).
Describing the ingress does not show the annotations.

Comment: could you paste your ingress.yaml file?

Comment: Did you try `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: route`?
Also, post ingress manifest. Will be helpful in debugging.

Comment: I running into the same problem and found this thread https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1980

Comment: Any update on this? I am facing a similar issue with web sockets.

Answer (score 4):

Because item host(in ingress.yml) cannot be empty or wildzard (*.example.com).

Make sure your host such as test.example.com(if u don't have dns, please config it in your local hosts),then test

```
curl -I  http://test.example.com/test/login.jsp
```

then u will see

```
Set-Cookie: route=ebfcc90982e244d1d7ce029b98f8786b; Expires=Sat, 03-Jan-70 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=172800; Domain=test.example.com; Path=/test; HttpOnly
```

The official example：

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-test
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"

spec:
  rules:
  - host: stickyingress.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```